# Crystal report export in excel

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

Having problem in my crystal report, exporting to excel. Can somebody help me how to code or any suggestion code that will catch if the file you exported is already exist?

For example, you exported lotinfo the next will be lotinfo2 then lotinfo3 etc, my code is always exporting single file and single name.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
        Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
        DiskFileDestinationOptions()
        Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New ExcelFormatOptions
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _
                                    "c:\Lot Enterprise Information.xls"
        CrExportOptions = crypt.ExportOptions
        With CrExportOptions
            .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
            .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel
            .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
            .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
        End With
        crypt.Export()
        MessageBox.Show("LOT ENTERPRISE INFORMATION IS SUCCESSFULLY EXPORTED!, LOCATED AT DRIVE C:", "PLEASE CHECK AT DRIVE C:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please Select Specific date to convert!")
        'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this function for quite some time now. Just fix it up depending on your use.

```
Private Function fileExists(ByVal path As String, ByVal filename As String) As String
   ' This function basically adds a counter when the file already exists
   ' eg filename
   ' filename(1)
   ' filename(2) 

   Dim counter As Integer = 0
   Dim orginialFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename)
   Dim newFileName = orginialFileName
   Dim extension As String = ""
   Dim testIndex As Integer = 0
   While File.Exists(newFileName)
      counter = counter + 1
      extension = newFileName.Substring(newFileName.LastIndexOf("."))

      filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("."))
      testIndex = filename.LastIndexOf("(")
      If testIndex <> -1 Then
          filename = filename.Substring(0, testIndex)
      End If

      newFileName = String.Format("{0}({1})", System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename), counter.ToString())
      filename = String.Format("{0}({1})", filename, counter.ToString())

      newFileName += extension
      filename += extension
  End While

  Return filename
End Function
```

example usage

```
Dim output as string
output = fileExists("C:\test", "file.xls")
MsgBox(output)
```

[This](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/some_useful_vba_functions/) link might also be useful for you.

**EDIT:**

You can use it before your `Try-Catch` block

```
    Dim fullPath As String = "C:\fileinfo.xls"
    Dim directory, output, filename As String
    If File.Exists(fullPath) Then
        directory = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\"))
        filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        output = fileExists(directory, filename) 
        fullPath = path.combine(directory,output)
    End If
```

Then change this part

```
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _
                                    "c:\Lot Enterprise Information.xls"
```

To

```
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _
                                    fullPath
```

Comment: I tried to copy paste you code, but there is a error return 'File' is not declared. sorry im just a beginner with this. T_T

Comment: Put this on the uppermost part of your codes.
`Imports System.IO`

Comment: oh done with this file i import system.io, but still same problem there is no lotinfo 2 lotinfo 3

Comment: can you give me an advice how to apply it to my button1? thanks

Comment: First you have to identify if the file exists. If it does, then you can use the function fileExists. But before using the function, you have to separate the path into two parts. The directory = "C:\" and the filename "fileinfo.xls", then plug it in the function. The output from the function will be your new filename, then add it on your directory string.

Comment: There is no error output the program is running but still the same problem, When I exported my first data example january10 then it will save it to my drive c:, And if I want to export january11 it will replace the january 10 to 11. All I want is every time I exported the filname extension will continue example january1.xls january1(1).xls, january1(2).xls january1(3).xls etc. so that it will not replace

Comment: something is wrong on your code then. Try asking it on a different question.